# how to send special character json request sopaui

Tags: json, soapui

I am sending a json request to a Rest servive through SOPAUI.

```
POST http://xxxxxx.net:11080/v01/rest/login/auth HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 142
Host: xxxxxxxxxx:11080
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
{

      "loginName": "po1537",
      "password": "*@LMG6"l",
      "providerNumber": 'ParkOne537',
}
```

but getting Error like

```
<data contentType="text/plain" contentLength="235"><![CDATA[ParseError at  [row,col]:[0,86]
Message: Expected a ',' or '}' at character 86 of {"Login":{

      "loginName": "po1537",
      "password": "*@LMG6"l",
      "providerNumber": 'ParkOne537',

    }}. ]]></data>
```

This password is dynamically generated and sometime the password contains a double quote .I observed that sopaui throwing error if the value has a double quote in it.

Comment: How did you set up the request with generated password? With a Groovy script? You'll need to escape the double quote character somehow (`"` to `\"`)

Answer (score 0):

You got a trivial error. Remove `,` for the last key value pair.

Change from:

```
{
      "loginName": "po1537",
      "password": "*@LMG6"l",
      "providerNumber": 'ParkOne537',
}
```

To:

```
{
      "loginName": "po1537",
      "password": "*@LMG6"l",
      "providerNumber": 'ParkOne537'
}
```